# Dev C++ Wininet Upload file using HTTP

Tags: c++, http, file, upload, wininet

I want to upload "C:\test.txt" to webserver, when I am running program, file is not uploading and I am not getting any error.

[the complete C++ code can be find here](http://student114.110mb.com/upload.cpp.txt)

and php code on webserver can be find here: "http://student114.110mb.com/upload.txt" 
or 
"http://student114.110mb.com/upload.php"

kindly help me where I am doing wrong

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <wininet.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment(lib,"wininet.lib")

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    static TCHAR frmdata[] = "-----------------------------7d82751e2bc0858\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\"C:\test.txt\"\nContent-Type: text/plain\n\nfile contents  here\n-----------------------------7d82751e2bc0858--"; 
    static TCHAR hdrs[] = "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7d82751e2bc0858"; 

    HINTERNET hSession = InternetOpen("MyAgent",INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
     if(hSession==NULL)
    {
     cout<<"Error: InternetOpen";  
    }


    HINTERNET hConnect = InternetConnect(hSession, _T("localhost"),INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);
     if(hConnect==NULL)
    {
     cout<<"Error: InternetConnect";  
    }

    HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConnect, (const char*)"POST",_T("upload.php"), NULL, NULL, (const char**)"*/*\0", 0, 1);
    if(hRequest==NULL)
    {
     cout<<"Error: HttpOpenRequest";  
    }

    BOOL sent= HttpSendRequest(hRequest, hdrs, strlen(hdrs), frmdata, strlen(frmdata));
    if(!sent)
    {
     cout<<"Error: HttpSendRequest";
     }

    //close any valid internet-handles
    InternetCloseHandle(hSession);
    InternetCloseHandle(hConnect);
    InternetCloseHandle(hRequest);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you installed fiddler and seen what HTTP traffic is being sent? I'd start there first.

Comment: When I edited the source code then I got error "Error: HttpSendRequest 12005", see above hyperlink

Answer (score 5):

I was able to make your code work.

First of all the code on the link you provided and the code you posted is not the same:

```
InternetConnect(hSession, _T("localhost"), ...
InternetConnect(hSession, _T("http://student114.110mb.com"), ...
```

You must pass an host name or ip address here so "localhost" is good but "http://student114.110mb.com" isn't.
If you pass an URL you will get the 12005 error code [[see WinINet error codes on msdn]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385465%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Another problem is the frmdata string. You should double the backslash in C:\test.txt or you will get a tab character \t in your string. The \n before and after the delimiters should also be replaced by \r\n because RFC 1521 and most other internet protocols use CRLF as a line delimiter.

Here is the string I have used.

```
static TCHAR frmdata[] = "-----------------------------7d82751e2bc0858\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\"C:\\test.txt\"\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\nfile contents  here\r\n-----------------------------7d82751e2bc0858--\r\n";
```

Finally the PHP code doesn't work because you use $_FILES["file"] where you should be using $_FILES["uploadedfile"]. "uploadedfile" would typically correspond to the name of an <input type="file"> tag in HTML but in your case it is specified in the *name=* parameter of the frmdata[] string.

Here's the PHP code I have used to test this

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"], "/files/my_file");
```

When you work on complex client/server interaction like this it helps to test each part separately. You could for instance.

- Write a simple HTML upload form to
  test your php script
- Have your program send its request to
  netcat and examine the output

Answer (score 2):

you have to send a full request without the WinAPI if you want to have a good request for uploading a file over a php script.

In the past, I also tried to send such a request like you, with all the api functions.
But when I sniffed it with wireshark, I got the same solution like you: the header is merged and it didn't work.

So I used winsock again and it worked if the data which you want to send aren't too big.

here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//link libwsock32.a

unsigned long WinsockStart()
{
     WSADATA wsa;
     unsigned long ulong;
     struct hostent *host;

     if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsa) < 0)
     {
          cout << "Error WinsockStart()" << endl;
          WSACleanup();
          return 1;
          }

     if((host=gethostbyname("www.example.com"))<0)
     {
          cout << "Fehler gethostbyname()" << endl;
          WSACleanup();
          return 2;
          }

     ulong = *(unsigned long*) host->h_addr;

     return ulong;
      }

     void error_exit(string text)
     {
     cout << text;
     WSACleanup();
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }



int main()
{
SOCKET sock;
struct sockaddr_in addr;
unsigned long win=0;
int con = 0, gr=0, send_r=0, rec=0;
char header[2048], puffer[2018]; 
string to_send="hello world";
string name="test99.txt";

win=WinsockStart();
   if(win==1||win==2)
      error_exit("Error WinsockStart()");

addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
addr.sin_port=htons(80);
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = win;

sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
   if(sock<0)
      error_exit("Error socket()");

gr = (to_send.size()+name.size()+287);

sprintf(header, "POST /upload.php HTTP/1.1\r\n");
sprintf(header, "%sHost: www.example.com\r\n", header);
sprintf(header, "%sConnection: Keep-Alive\r\n", header);
sprintf(header, "%sContent-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------90721038027008\r\n", header);
sprintf(header, "%sContent-Length: %d\r\n", header, gr);
sprintf(header, "%s\r\n", header);
sprintf(header, "%s-----------------------------90721038027008\r\n", header);
sprintf(header, "%sContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upfile\"; filename=\"%s\"\r\n", header, name.c_str());
sprintf(header, "%sContent-Type: text/plain\r\n", header);
sprintf(header, "%s\r\n", header);
sprintf(header, "%s%s\r\n", header, to_send.c_str());
sprintf(header, "%s-----------------------------90721038027008\r\n", header);
sprintf(header, "%sContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"post\"\r\n", header);
sprintf(header, "%s\r\n", header);
sprintf(header, "%supload\r\n\r\n", header);
sprintf(header, "%s-----------------------------90721038027008--\r\n\r\n\0", header);      

con = connect(sock, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
   if(con < 0)
      error_exit("Error connect()");

if(send_r=send(sock, header, strlen(header), 0)<0)
      error_exit("Error send()");

 while(rec=recv(sock, puffer, 2048, 0))
 {
  if(rec==0)
    error_exit("Server quit");

 printf("%s", puffer);
 }               

closesocket(sock);
WSACleanup();
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Until now, I've searched and I've tried for other solutions using the WinHttpAPI, but I didn't find anything for my purposes.

Patrone

P.S. Sorry for my bad english, it's not my native language

Answer (score 1):

```
static TCHAR frmdata[] = "-----------------------------7d82751e2bc0858\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\"C:\\test.txt\"\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\nfile contents  here\r\n-----------------------------7d82751e2bc0858--\r\n";
```

Last "--" characters should be before the "-----------------------------7d82751e2bc0858" boundary, not after it.

Correct code:

```
static TCHAR frmdata[] = "-----------------------------7d82751e2bc0858\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\"C:\\test.txt\"\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\nfile contents  here\r\n-------------------------------7d82751e2bc0858\r\n";
```