# Upload text file using wininet in c++

Tags: php, c++

I'm going to upload `text.txt` file using wininet.
Here is a code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "windows.h"
#include "wininet.h"
#include "tchar.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "string"
#include "sstream"

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Wininet.lib")

int main(){

        TCHAR hdrs[] = _T("Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7d82751e2bc0858");
TCHAR frmdata[] = _T("-----------------------------7d82751e2bc0858\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\"C:\\Users\Ahmer\Desktop\asd\test.txt\"\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\nfile contents  here\r\n-----------------------------7d82751e2bc0858--\r\n");
LPCTSTR accept[] = {_T("*/*"), NULL};

HINTERNET hSession = InternetOpen(_T("MyAgent"), INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
HINTERNET hConnect = InternetConnect(hSession, _T("http://localhost/cpp/"), INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);
HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConnect, _T("POST"), _T("uploadfile.php"), NULL, NULL, accept, 0, 1);
BOOL sent = HttpSendRequest(hRequest, hdrs, _tcslen(hdrs), frmdata, _tcslen(frmdata));

    if(hSession==NULL)
{
 cout<<"Error: InternetOpen";  
}
if(hConnect==NULL)
{
 cout<<"Error: InternetConnect";  
}
if(hRequest==NULL)
{
 cout<<"Error: HttpOpenRequest";  
}
if(!sent)
{
 cout<<"Error: HttpSendRequest";
 }
  //close any valid internet-handles
   InternetCloseHandle(hSession);
   InternetCloseHandle(hConnect);
   InternetCloseHandle(hRequest);

   return 0;

    }
```

Here is a php file.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"], "/FileFolder");
```

there is error `Error: HttpOpenRequest`. What is the problem with this code. 
I read a question from here but in this question user did not paste the code rather than give the link of website which is closed now so this is not helpfull now.
[Dev C++ Wininet Upload file using HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985345/dev-c-wininet-upload-file-using-http)

But I find the php code from there.

Comment: How is your server set up with the PHP code? What's the error message you get with the HTTP request?

Comment: How about closing the connection and everything else again before terminating the program?

Comment: yes there is error in `Error: HttpOpenRequest` I update the code know see this.